# Add extra filter to datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have one datatable which i want to add extra filter.so i have write following code

```
$('.sam-table').dataTable({
    initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns(1).every( function () {
                var column = this;
              var extradiv=$("<div id='extra_filter'></div>").insertAfter( $('#DataTables_Table_0_length label'));
                var select = $('<select class="form-control input-sm"><option value="">User Level</option></select>')
                  .appendTo(extradiv)
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        ); 
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    var user_type = getUrlVars()["user_type"];
                    if(d==user_type){
                      alert('equal');
                    }
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            });
          }
    });
```

but that is not working. i have check firebug but there is no error too. here is my link to jsfiddle. can anyone please check it and let me suggest where i am wrong.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8cxj99ht/2/)

Comment: Can you please tell which column you want to sort and in which order?

Comment: What do you mean 'that is not working'? What are you trying to do - add a selectlist on each row?